# Template Engine for User-Provided Templats

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

I am looking for an efficient, fast & most importantly, secure template engine that I can integrate it with my CMS.

This engine will process user-submitted templates and generate the output (similar to Shopify user-provided template).

While researching, I've found Twig (with the Sandbox option), and, very interesting, the actual engine used on Shopify http://code.google.com/p/php-liquid/

Do you have any experience with this type of system?
I was thinking of building one from scratch, but I can better spend the time developing unique features.

PS: The engine should be in PHP.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use Twig on pretty regular basis an LOVE it, but i havent used it as stated in your use case, so i dunno. I have also developed some Shopify layouts for acquaintances in the past.

Id say if you plan on using Twig for the templating of the rest of the application (ie. the trusted code) then just use Twig - no sense in adding another tool to the chain unless it has specific non-trivial features you need that Twig doesnt.

OTH if you dont plan on using Twig for anything else then you could go either way. Although, from looking at your google code link it looks like that project is dead unless they have just moved to Github or something. The last commits to trunk were in 2006 :-(

Comment: @narcis: Ahh there we go. In that case, its still worth consideration.

Comment: One advantage of this method would be re-usable templates & a lot of people are used to Liquid

Comment: Thats very true... I would stick with whichever one you plan to use for the rest of the templating (assuming youre going to use template engine instead of raw php)